# How to convert object to Datetime index in python pandas without jumbled up the Datetime as well as the format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format, python-datetime

[image]

I have converted an object(string) to a Datetime object. But in some rows the datetime format changed. So when ever I made any calculation upon that database it becomes totally wrong. How to solve that?